# Ordering of async_writes incorrect even when using strand

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a program that forwards data that is reads to another peer.
I have a method that is being called after each read of data on socket. This method posts the data in a strand to write it back to another peer. When sending big chunks of data, the data sent back by the application is not the same as the one received, the problem is that the data is not ordered anymore. This is only the case when using multiple threads in the boost::asio::io_service.

handleGatewayReply is called when some data is read on the socket. 
At this point (1), after writing data in a file, I can see that the data is still ordered.
After that, postBackendReply is being called and the data is still ordered(2).
However in SessionConnection::postReply, if I flush the data to a file (3), I can see that the data is not ordered anymore.
I cannot see why the order is lost at this point, I tried to use a strand in handleGatewayReply and in postBackendReply (as shown in the code), but the behavior is still the same.

Sorry I cannot submit a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example because the bug is too hard to spot, required multithreading forwarding of a lot of data.

```
  void Reply::handleGatewayReply(std::stringstream* stream)
  {
    // Flush data to file (1)
    m_strand.post(std::bind([=]() {  
        postBackendReply(*stream);
      delete stream;
    }
    }));

  }

void Reply::postBackendReply(const std::stringstream& stream)
  {
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<Buffer>();
    buffer->m_buffers.push_back(stream.str());
    // Flush data to file (2)
    auto connection = m_request->connection();
    if (connection) {
//    connection->postReply(buffer); // doesn't work either
          m_strand.post(std::bind(&SessionConnection::postReply, connection,buffer));
    }

  }


  void SessionConnection::postReply(BufferPtr buffer)
  {
      // Flush data to file (3)
      m_ioService.post(
        m_ostrand.wrap(
          std::bind(&SessionConnection::sendNext, 
                    shared_from_this(), buffer)));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a strand:

1. never post any handler direct to the `io_service` - that is guaranteed to lose ordering and break concurrency guarantees.
2. `strand::wrap` every async handler.
3. in a (wrapped) handler, if you need to force order, `dispatch` to the strand. Only `post` to it if the posted handler is still valid if executed at some point in the future.

example:

```
thing.async_op(mystrand.wrap([self = shared_from_this()](auto&& error){
    self->mystrand.dispatch(&must_be_done_now_A);
    self->mystrand.post(&may_be_done_out_of_order_B);
    self->mystrand.dispatch(&must_be_done_now_C);
});
```

execution order will be:

1. `thing`'s handler
2. `must_be_done_now_A`
3. `must_be_done_now_C`
4. `thing`'s handler finishes
5. *any other stuff that got into the `io_service` in the meantime*
6. `may_be_done_out_of_order_B`

Comment: 1. I never post a handler directly to io_service, I always use a strand
2. every async_write handler is wrapped in a strand already
3. I tried to replace the post with dispatch, but same problem. Any other idea ? why is it ordered in Reply::postBackendReply (so here no problem with the order) but not in postReply? What can happen here ?

Comment: @BenD if you don't wrap your handlers all ordering is luck.

Comment: @BenD in your function `postReply` you are effectively posting a post. order is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is really helpful, can you explain more clearly what's the difference between an io_service.post(strand.wrap(...)) and strand.post(...)

Comment: strand::wrap returns a function which when executed, posts a function to the strand. But this function-posting-function is being posted directly to the io_service, not the strand. So it is executed out of order with respect to other handlers pending in the strand.